# Is commutator subgroup contained in every normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I know that factor group of any normal group is not abelian. But factor group of commutator is normal.
As every commutator is normal subgroup and one property that 
Let G be a group and G' is commutator subgroup then
If H is normal group of G then G\H is abelian iff G' is contained in H.
That means there are normal group which doesnot contain commutator.
Can any one please provide example that such thing happen.
i.e. example of normal group not containing commutator group.

Comment: The trivial subgroup is always normal and will never contain the commutator subgroup unless the group was abelian to begin with.

Comment: If $G$ is a non-abelian group then $\{e\}$ is a normal subgroup not contained in the commutator subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem tells you exactly where to look: $G'\subseteq H$ iff $G/H$ is abelian, so what you need to do is to find a group $G$ with a normal subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ is not abelian, and you will automatically get that $G'\not\subseteq H$. Taking $H = \{e\}$ works nicely if $G$ is non-abelian.

For a non-trivial example (the smallest non-trivial example, I think), take $G = S_3\times \Bbb Z_2$, and $H = \{e\}\times \Bbb Z_2$.